# Back-in-time disk usage

Tags: backup, encryption, disk-usage, hard-link, backintime

I am using Back-in-time with encryption on a remote server (ext4 FS). I am aware that for an unencrypted backup, BiT uses hard links. Thus in nautilus, the folder size appears to be huge. The actual usage can be tracked using `du` from [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/backintime/+question/146072) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/27129/696268). However I am not sure about the same for encrypted backups. The `du` seems to be growing per backup set.

My questions are:

1. Do the hard links work even for the encrypted backups? In other words, are encrypted versions of the same file under different backup sets same or different?
2. How do I find the *actual* disk usage per backup set? (Apart from the simple for loop: `for d in $(ls -d backup_dir/*/);do du -ksh $d;done`). Can this be a feature-request for BiT?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
I am using BiT 1.1.12 on Ubuntu 18.04. The remote system is RHEL 5.1.

Comment: I am using BiT 1.1.12 on Ubuntu 18.04. The remote system is RHEL 5.1.

Comment: please add your comment to your question, the comments are not intended to stay forever